# Problem with the balance package introducing empty pages at the end of the chapter

Tags: two-column

As stated in the title, I have a problem with the balance package.
The easiest is to have a look at the MWE and its output. There is an empty unnumbered page introduced unnecessarily at the end of the chapter. That way, some chapters no longer start on recto pages. Is there a way to avoid this page?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 9pt, twocolumn]{memoir} %
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}

\begin{document}
\balance
\chapter*{Chapter finishing on a recto page}
\lipsum
\chapter*{Chapter finishing on a verso page}
\lipsum\lipsum
\chapter*{Third chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is missing a document class, including whatever option is being used to make it two-column. I can't duplicate the result with the book class.

Comment: I edited the example

Comment: I have read the manual without really understanding it, but it seems to me that the output is significantly dependent on where you put the `\balance` (and `\nobalance`) macros in your code. The manual does mention chapters with many last pages.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to make it work with the balance package. Using \balance and \no balance at different positions in the code didn't make any difference.

However, I've found a compromise that is good enough with the flushend package and the command \flushcolsend that has to be given on the page to equilibrate. The final code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 9pt, twocolumn]{memoir} %
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\flushend
\chapter*{Chapter finishing on a recto page}

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext

\flushcolsend

\blindtext

\chapter*{Chapter finishing on a verso page}

\lipsum\lipsum

\flushcolsend

\blindtext
\chapter*{Third chapter}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```